# PHP 7 despues de reinstalar el wamp estoy teniendo problemas al volver a poner mi web en funcionamiento

Tags: php, php7, wamp

Desde que reinstale el **WAMP** he intentado usar mi **pag web** (el login, registro)  he intento registrar a alguien y no me deja, me dice que tengo un error. LLevo mirando bastante tiempo que puede ser realmente tendria que ir **una vez lo suba de nuevo al directorio** `/www/`. He estado tocando alguna cosa pero es que he llegado a la conclusion de que si esta como antes de **borrar el wamp** tendria que ir.

Mi `conexion.php` es :

```
<?php 


    class Conexion{

        private $servidor = "localhost";
        private $usuario  = "root";
        private $bd = "usuarios_mensaje";
        private $password = "";

        public function conectar(){
            $conexion = mysqli_connect($this->servidor,$this->usuario,$this->password,$this->bd);

            return $conexion;       
        }   


    }


    $conexion = new Conexion();
    // var_dump($conexion);

    var_dump($conexion->conectar());


 ?>
```

Pero sale todo bien, realmente no entiendo que puede cambiar para que ahora no vaya..

Cuando hago el registro se llama a un **fichero intermedio** (`registrar_usuario.php`)

```
<?php 

    require_once "../conexion.php";
    require_once "../controllers/usuario.php";

    session_start();    

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



    $datos = array(
     "nombre"=>$nombre,
     "apellidos"=>$apellidos,
     "usuario"=>$usuario,
     "email"=>$email,
     "password"=>$password
    );


    //eliminamos las sesiones de errores para evitar 'falsos errores' y que no se queden guardadas innecesariamente 
    unset($_SESSION['error_usuario']) ;
    unset($_SESSION['error_email']) ;
    unset($_SESSION['datos']);


    $usuario_controller = new Usuario();

    //Compruebo si el nombreUsuario y el email estan disponibles
    if ($usuario_controller->existeUsuario($datos['usuario'])) {
        $_SESSION['error_usuario'] = true;
    }

    if ($usuario_controller->existeEmail($datos['email'])) {
        $_SESSION['error_email'] = true;
    }


    if (isset($_SESSION['error_email']) || isset( $_SESSION['error_usuario'])) {
        //si las sessiones de errores estan alguna llenas manda al registro de nuevo  informando de que hay errores
        $_SESSION['datos'] = $datos;
        header("location: ../register.php");
    }

    else{



        //aqui pasa si esta DISPONIBLE el usuario y el email

        //borro las sesiones de errores

        unset($_SESSION['error_usuario'] );
        unset($_SESSION['error_email'] );

        //encriptando la contraseña
        $datos['password'] = password_hash($datos['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);




        //si es exitosa la insercion
        if ($usuario_controller->insertar($datos) == 1) {




            //redireccionamiento al 'inicio_sesion'
            //header("location:../login.php");
        }
        else{


            var_dump($datos);

            echo "Fallo al crear el usuario";

        }
    }







 ?>
```

Y acaba dando el error que esta dentro del final `else{}` que dice : `Fallo al crear el usuario`.  He tocado ya todo y no estoy dando con la tecla, no se si es algodel **wamp** .. La **version** del PHP del wamp es la `7.2.14`. 
Agradeceria cualquier dato que pudieran aportar al respecto.

**EDICION**

**Funcion añadir usuario'**

```
public function insertar($datos){


    $conexion = $this->c->conectar();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) 
            VALUES('{$datos['nombre']}','{$datos['apellidos']}','{$datos['usuario']}','{$datos['email']}','{$datos['password']}')";

    return $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    // return $result = $conexion->query($sql);

}
```

Comment: Y esto: ***`$usuario_controller = new Usuario();`*** ¿no lleva ningún parámetro de inicialización? Es que no lo veo claro.

Comment: No, es que eso lo uso a modo de controlador, mas adelante uso sus **metodos** que **si** llevan parametros como este :`$usuario_controller->insertar($datos)`

Comment: si reinstalaste wamp volviste a crear la base de datos??

Comment: sisi, esta todo igual

Comment: cual es el código de la función insertar?

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta y añado la funcion

Comment: ¿Qué error recibes? ¿Aparece algo en los logs?

Comment: Realmente el error que me da no es ningun `warning` de php es un display que yo puse que dice : **Fallo al crear el usuario.** . Es el ultimo `else` de mi fichero `registrar_usuario.php`

Comment: Por cierto, el código parece que puede ser susceptible a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de generar sentencias SQL concatenando cadenas.

Comment: Eso lo tratare cuando solucione esto. Gracias le echare un vistazo mas adelante.

Comment: Para la insercion del usuario que uso `$conexion->query($sql)`  o  `mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)`

Comment: Si te dice `Fallo al crear el usuario` eso es parte del tu código, ¿no?, es un `else`... entonces el programa está entrando ahí y tú tienes que depurar tus variables para verificar por qué está entrando ahí.